# How Change Color Row in GridView when I want Apply condition it Row in C# & WPF, how to do it?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

How Change Color Row in Grid View when I want Apply condition it Row in C# & WPF, how to do it?

(Working in C# and WPF)

Note 1: columns Grid View is: Product ID, Product Name, ProductStartDate, Product Type  and  Product Price.

Note  2: cell index Zero in Grid View  is  Product ID, cell index One in Grid View  is  Product Name , cell  index Two in Grid View is ProductStartDate , cell index Three in Grid View is Product Type, cell index four in Grid View is Product Price.

Note 3: Data Type Column Product Type in Grid View is string and value it is "Sale" value  or "Buy"  value.

My Code:

```
int   gridviewrowcount = gridview1.items.count;
string  type;
for(int i = 0; i <= gridviewrowcount-1 ; i++)
{
  type = gridview1.columns[3].GetCellContent(gridview1.items[i]) as TextBlock;    
}
```

This code Get gridview1.columns [3] text value in variable string type.

But, i need gridview1.columns [3] text value is "sale" Change Color Row it

in Grid View is Green color. And i need gridview1.columns [3] text value is

"Buy" Change Color Row it in Grid View is Red color?

(Working in C# and WPF)

Thank's in advance

Comment: have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-style-a-row-in-a-listview-that-implements-a-gridview

Answer (score 0):

To conditional formatting the GridView in WPF, you will need to handle the `LoadingRow` event.

Bellow I'm showing a sample code you can accomplish the result. I supposed that you are population the GridView with a `IEnumerable<T>` of some Model class, that I've called `ProductModel`, with a public property named `ProductType`.

You can put this code on the constructor of your Form / View class.

```
//Row Style.
gridview1.LoadingRow += (_sender, _e) =>
    {
        ProdutctModel item = (ProductModel)_e.Row.DataContext;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.ProductType.Equals("Buy"))
                _e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            else if (item.ProductType.Equals("Sale"))
                _e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    };
```

As you can see are simple, you just need change the `Row.Foreground` according to the Product Type, as you want.